# neo4j single pass over graph but multiple matches

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a graph in neo4j with vertices of:

```
person:ID,name,value:int,:LABEL
1,Alice,1,Person
2,Bob,0,Person
3,Charlie,0,Person
4,David,0,Person
5,Esther,0,Person
6,Fanny,0,Person
7,Gabby,0,Person
8,XXXX,1,Person
```

and edges:

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
1,2,call
2,3,text
3,2,text
6,3,text
5,6,text
5,4,call
4,1,call
4,5,text
1,5,call
1,8,call
6,8,call
6,8,text
8,6,text
7,1,text
```

imported into neo4j like:

```
DATA_DIR_SAMPLE=/data_network/
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-admin import --mode=csv \
  --database=graph.db \
  --nodes:Person ${DATA_DIR_SAMPLE}/vertices.csv \
  --relationships ${DATA_DIR_SAMPLE}/edges.csv
```

which looks like:
[image]

Now when querying the graph like:

```
MATCH (source:Person)-[*1]-(destination:Person)
RETURN source.name, source.value, avg(destination.value), 'undir_1_any' as type
UNION ALL
MATCH (source:Person)-[*2]-(destination:Person)
RETURN source.name, source.value, avg(destination.value), 'undir_2_any' as type
```

one can see that the graph is traversed multiple times, and additionally as I want to obtain a table like:

```
Vertex | value | type_undir_1_any | type_undir_2_any
Alice  | 1     | 0.2              |  0
```

an additional aggregation step (pivot/reshape) would be required

[image]

In the future, I would like to add the following patterns

- undirected  | directed
- all relations | type of relation
- as outlined up to 3 levels into the graph
  and all permutations of these

**Is there a better way to combine the queries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate along the path length, while with a custom function of calculating the average value:

```
MATCH p = (source:Person)-[*1..2]-(destination:Person)
WITH 
  length(p) as L, source, destination
RETURN 
  source.name as Vertex, 
  source.value as value, 
  1.0 * 
      sum(CASE WHEN L = 1 THEN destination.value ELSE 0 END) / 
      sum(CASE WHEN L = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type_undir_1_any,
  1.0 * 
      sum(CASE WHEN L = 2 THEN destination.value ELSE 0 END) /
      sum(CASE WHEN L = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as type_undir_2_any
```

Or a more elegant version with function from the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions) to calculate the average on the collection:

```
MATCH p = (source:Person)-[*1..2]-(destination:Person)
RETURN 
  source.name as Vertex, 
  source.value as value,
  apoc.coll.avg(COLLECT(
    CASE WHEN length(p) = 1 THEN destination.value ELSE NULL END
  )) as type_undir_1_any,
  apoc.coll.avg(COLLECT(
    CASE WHEN length(p) = 2 THEN destination.value ELSE NULL END
  )) as type_undir_2_any
```

Comment: Great. This works well for addressing several levels. How could this be expanded to also address the different types of relation (any, only call, only text) i.e. producing` #depth * typeOfRelation` outputs?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler You can combine any conditions for the collection, including the type of relationship in it: `CASE WHEN length(p) = 1 AND ALL(r in relationships(p) where type(r)='text') THEN destination.value ELSE NULL END`

Comment: I see - but this quickly will lead to not real well maintainable code considering that `list(itertools.product(*[['text', 'call', 'both'],
                         ['1','2','3', '1..2', '1..3'],
                         ['undirected', 'src->dst', 'src<-dst']]))` will already contain 48 combinations.

Comment: I do not think there is any other way to solve it. But it will be interesting to learn it))

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer! - I will accept it as it is already close.